# Why does "pip install Plone" fail with "KeyError: 'z3c'"?

Tags: plone, pip

> $ pip install Plone

installed a lot of packages but then aborted with this error:

```
 File "/Users/rob/.virtualenvs/plone/bin/../lib/python2.7/site.py", line 172, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'z3c'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Plone` does not support installation via `pip`, even though it can be found as a Python package with `pip search Plone`.

I found this out by asking this question on the `#plone` IRC channel.

Per @SteveM's comment, easy_install and setup_tools just can't deal with all the known-good-set issues for an application with as many dependencies as Plone. That's what buildout is good for.

References: 
[Full trace of error](http://pastebin.com/jhg6KRG0)
[Reasons why it fails](http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/pip-install-Plone-td5287792.html)

Comment: There really isn't any such thing as a "pip" package. It's a Python package, listed on PyPI.
pip, easy_install and setup_tools just can't deal with all the known-good-set issues for an application with as many dependencies as Plone. That's what buildout is good for.

Comment: Clarified this in README so that we would avoid further issues like this when people try to self-install Plone https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/commit/f829957027d3234d8241b27b9d30153e6002dff0

Answer (score 3):

The problem was likely in z3c.objpath 1.0 which did not have namespace declaration. Fixed and released in z3c.objpath 1.1.

(I had the same error when trying to build Plone docs on RTD via pip.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Plone with pip try [plock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plock).